# How to display all points on an AmCharts stock chart without grouping using API

Tags: graph, amcharts, amstock

How can an AmChart stock chart be created using the API approach that does not combine all data items by day?

[image: chart results]

Using the API, the data points are always combined into a day, like this:

```
// API approach
var chart = new AmCharts.AmStockChart();
var dataSet = new AmCharts.DataSet();
...
```

https://codepen.io/AlienTechnology/pen/ALKNGa?editors=0010

Using the JSON approach, a line graph can be created that does not group. Here is the same chart using JSON:

```
/// JSON approach
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "stock",
   ...
```

https://codepen.io/AlienTechnology/pen/VKaNLP?editors=0010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One good thing about the JSON approach is, that you find mistakes faster and easier.
And that's exact the thing that happened to you. Comparing both your codepens shows, that you appended the `categoryAxesSettings` to the panel and not to the chart (where it belongs to).

```
var caSettings = new AmCharts.CategoryAxesSettings();
caSettings.minPeriod = "mm";
caSettings.maxSeries = 0;
chart.categoryAxesSettings = caSettings;
```

Here's the working [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKqXQN?editors=0010).

Comment: How would using the JSON approach help find this mistake faster?

Comment: I would say its much easier to read and comprehend cause it reflects the hierarchy of the amchart objects you create with it. It also reduces a lot of overhead because you don't have to write object names over and over again.